# Split json data using comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json which has a key "tag", which is returning data like this
    "tags": "jname,gender,city"

but i want to append these value in separate span like below

```
<div class="info">
<span>jname</span><span>gender</span><span>city</span>
</div>
```

I am trying with this

```
 $.getJSON("data.json", function(tagsposts) {

        var items = [];
    splitsVal = tag.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < splitsVal.length; i++) {
       obj.push({name:splitsVal[i]});
        obj[i] = '<span>' + obj[i] + '</span>';
        $('.tags-div').append(obj[i])
    }
   $.each(tagsposts, function(key, val) {
       items.push('<a href="#">' + val['tags'] + '</a>');
   });
   $('#tagsposts').append(items.join(""));
});
```

Am I doing correct

Comment: I don't know, are you? You have to specify what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you doing it correctly? Does it work? Can't you test it to see if it's correct?

Comment: its not populating any data

Comment: Where is `obj` declared?

Comment: yes something is getting wrong thats why data is not populating, need your help and suggestion

Comment: @Sajal If you can control the format the value corresponding to "tags" then why not make it a json list?

Comment: Maybe you want something like this?
 Not sure though `$('.info').append(tag.split(',').map(e => '<a href="#"><span>' + e + '</span></a>').join(''))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to split an undefined variable:

```
function(tagsposts) {
    var items = [];
    splitsVal = tag.split(","); // but tag doesn't exist...
```

(If you look at your browser console, which you should get into the habit of doing, you'll get a very clear message about why this isn't working: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: tag".)

Since you haven't provided your JSON it's not possible to say exactly how to fix this.  Assuming the full JSON is of the form

```
{"tag": "foo,bar,baz"}
```

then you would want

```
splitsVal = tagsposts.tag.split(",")
```

If there's more structure than that inside the JSON, you'll need to crawl down through that parsed object to find the "tag" value(s) you need.

There are lots of other problems here, however.

You also try to push onto an undefined array named `obj`; you'd need at least a `var obj = []` outside that `for` loop.  Though it's not clear why you're using `obj` at all, or trying to draw an object `{name: val}` into the DOM instead of just the value.  What you're trying to do is just read `splitsVal[i]` so you can just do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < splitsVal.length; i++) {
    $('.tags-div').append('<span>'+splitsVal[i]+'</span>')
}
```

And you try to iterate over `tagsposts` as if it's an array when generating the `#tagsposts` contents. (Is your JSON an array? If so you need to iterate over it when getting the `tag` values too.)

Comment: Thanks for the help